# h:panelGroup and colspan making my table messed up

Tags: html, css, jsf-2

My table used to look like this:

[image]

There is an icon on the right of each field telling the user if what he entered is accepted. The icons used to be really close to the field. But once I added two other fields with a colspan it looks like this :

[image]

and it looks okayish when the field is not accepted, which makes no sens since both images are supposed to be in the same place.

[image]

Here is the code :

```
   <table class="registration">             

            <!-- username -->
            <tr><td>
            <h:outputLabel for="username">#{registering.Username}: </h:outputLabel></td><td>
        <p:inputText id="username" value="#{subscribeUser.user.username}" 
            validator="#{usernameValidator.validate}" maxlength="#{values.small}">
            <f:passThroughAttribute name="required" value="true"/>
            <f:ajax event="blur" render="usernameCheck usernameMessage submit"></f:ajax>
        </p:inputText></td><td>
        <h:panelGroup id="usernameCheck">
            <h:graphicImage library="images/icons" name="failed_indicator.png" rendered="#{usernameValidator.isIndicatorVisible.usernameFailed}"></h:graphicImage>
            <h:graphicImage library="images/icons" name="success_indicator.png" rendered="#{usernameValidator.isIndicatorVisible.usernameSuccess}"></h:graphicImage>
        </h:panelGroup></td><td>
        <span class="error"><h:message id="usernameMessage" for="username"/></span></td>
        </tr>

        <!-- password -->           

        <tr><td>
        <h:outputLabel for="password">#{registering.Password}: </h:outputLabel></td><td>
        <p:password id="password" value="#{subscribeUser.userCredential.password}" feedback="true"

            promptLabel="#{registering.PleaseEnterPass}" weakLabel="#{registering.Weak}"
                  goodLabel="#{registering.Good}" strongLabel="#{registering.Strong}"
            requiredMessage="#{registering.reqPassword}"
            validator="#{passwordValidator.validate}">
            <f:passThroughAttribute name="required" value="true"/>
            <f:attribute name="confirm" value="#{confirmPassword}" />
            <f:passThroughAttribute name="required" value="true"/>
            <f:ajax event="blur" execute="password confirmPassword" render="passwordMessage passwordCheck confpasswordCheck submit"></f:ajax>                       
        </p:password></td><td>
        <h:panelGroup id="passwordCheck">
            <h:graphicImage library="images/icons" name="failed_indicator.png" rendered="#{passwordValidator.isIndicatorVisible.passwordFailed}"></h:graphicImage>
            <h:graphicImage library="images/icons" name="success_indicator.png" rendered="#{passwordValidator.isIndicatorVisible.passwordSuccess}"></h:graphicImage>
        </h:panelGroup>
        </td><td>
        <span class="error"><h:message id="passwordMessage" for="password"/></span></td>
        </tr>           

        <!-- Confirm password -->

        <tr><td>
        <h:outputLabel for="confirmPassword" value="#{registering.ConfirmPass}: "/></td><td>
        <p:password id="confirmPassword" required="true"
            requiredMessage="#{registering.PleaseConfirmPassword}" 
            binding="#{confirmPassword}">
            <f:passThroughAttribute name="required" value="true"/>
            <f:ajax event="blur" execute="password confirmPassword" render="passwordMessage passwordCheck confpasswordCheck submit"></f:ajax>

            </p:password> </td><td>
            <h:panelGroup id="confpasswordCheck">
                <h:graphicImage library="images/icons" name="failed_indicator.png" rendered="#{passwordValidator.isIndicatorVisible.passwordFailed}"></h:graphicImage>
                <h:graphicImage library="images/icons" name="success_indicator.png" rendered="#{passwordValidator.isIndicatorVisible.passwordSuccess}"></h:graphicImage>
            </h:panelGroup>

            </td><td>
        <span class="error"><h:message id="passwordConfMessage" for="confirmPassword" /></span></td>
        </tr>

        <!-- Email -->

        <tr><td>
            <h:outputLabel for="email">#{registering.Email}: </h:outputLabel></td><td>
        <p:inputText id="email" required="true" value="#{subscribeUser.user.email}" 
            validator="#{emailValidator.validate}"
            requiredMessage="#{registering.reqEmail}">
            <f:passThroughAttribute name="required" value="true"/>
            <f:passThroughAttribute name="type" value="email"/>
            <f:passThroughAttribute name="maxlength" value="100"/>
            <f:ajax event="blur" render="emailCheck emailMessage submit"></f:ajax>

        </p:inputText></td><td>
         <h:panelGroup id="emailCheck">
            <h:graphicImage library="images/icons" name="failed_indicator.png" rendered="#{emailValidator.isIndicatorVisible.emailFailed}"></h:graphicImage>
            <h:graphicImage library="images/icons" name="success_indicator.png" rendered="#{emailValidator.isIndicatorVisible.emailSuccess}"></h:graphicImage>
        </h:panelGroup> </td><td>
        <span class="error"><h:message id="emailMessage" for="email"/></span></td>
        </tr>

        <!-- Country -->

                <tr><td>
        <h:outputLabel for="country" value="#{registering.Country}:"></h:outputLabel></td>
        <td colspan="3"><p:selectOneMenu required="true" editable="false" id="country" value="#{subscribeUser.user.countryBean}" converter="#{countriesConverter}" effect="fold">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{registering.SelectCountry}" itemValue="#{null}" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{countriesConverter.countries}" var="country" itemLabel="#{country.shortName}" itemValue="#{country}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Timezone -->   

                     <tr><td>
        <h:outputLabel for="timezone">#{registering.Timezone}: </h:outputLabel></td>
        <td colspan="3">
            <p:selectOneMenu id="timezone" editable="false" required="true" value="#{subscribeUser.timezoneOffset}" converter="#{timezonesConverter}" effect="fold" >
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{registering.SelectTimezone}" itemValue="#{null}" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{timezonesConverter.timezonesList}" var="timezone" itemLabel="#{timezone.name}" itemValue="#{timezone}"  />
                </p:selectOneMenu></td>
        </tr>     
    </table>
```

I don't understand how I can make it work. I tried with primefaces p:row but it's the same problem. I reluctant to use another table for the two last field and align them with those above them because when the page is resized it's messed up as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the closeness was your only concern, I suggest you to get back to the first example and write in css something like this:

```
.registration td:last-child{
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

or try with `nth-child(desired-child-number)`.

Beside this, I suggest you to use `<h:panelGrid columns="3">` as a container. You will have:

1. first column as a placeholder, i.e. field description,
2. second column will be the field,
3. and third column will be the success/error messagefor input value

I have used it and it works fine. Plus you can add the css rules I previous mentioned

Comment: This does not work unfortunately. You see my field td cell is resized when the field is correct (which is odd really). Thus having a margin just make it a bit further from where it already is if that makes sens.

Comment: But actually I think your comment and my answer made me realize the root of my problem. When the field is empty the td cell takes the whole width that it can take. When the field is correct it takes the whole width aswell minus the width of the correct icon. But when it's incorrect it takes the width is lesser because of the message that appears next to it. I'm gonna give the field a fixed width and see if it works. Thanks anyway for driving me in the right direction.

Comment: I am glad you made it. I didn't mention the stuff you wrote, maybe I assumed you took that into account. Anyway, be cautious with jsf components, they can serve you a lot, but they can generate a lot of code, with "weird" ids and js events

Comment: I didn't make it work though. I tried a fixed value and making td inline block. I'm gonna keep on searching now as I was away for the day.